# Probability measure vs integral of probability density function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

As part of a larger article, I am busy writing a shorthand derivation / evaluation of the expected value of a random variable $X$:

$\mathop{{}\mathbb{E^Q}}[f(X)] = \mathop{{}\int_{-{\infty}}^{\infty}}f(X) \cdot d \mathbb{Q}(S)$

Here $\mathbb{Q}$ is a probability measure and $S$ is distributed lognormally with $F_S(x)$ the cumulative distribution function of $S$.

From the reference articles that I am using, I deduce that that the following is true:

$\begin{aligned} \mathop{{}\mathbb{E^Q}}[f(X)] 
&= \mathop{{}\int_{-{\infty}}^{\infty}}f(X) \cdot d \mathbb{Q}(S) \\ 
&= \mathop{{}\int_{-{\infty}}^{\infty}}f(X) \cdot d {F}(S) \\  
\end{aligned}$

In other words, loosely speaking, we are saying that $\mathbb{Q} \approx F$.

Question:

I am seeking the correct mathematical phrasing that justifies equating / substituting $d \mathbb{Q}$ with $d F$

**EDIT**:

Below is a screenshot from the source reference to help explain what I am trying to achieve / understand. To address the comments; firstly thank you. Secondly I have never heard of the pushforward measure and on that basis I doubt it is related, but I am not an expert on measure theory by any means of the word so it may very well be related.

Here $S$ represents the stochastic process followed by a stock / share in a company:

$ dS = \mu S dt + \sigma S d {W}_t $

where $dW_t$ is a Wiener process indexed by time $t$ and $ \sim N(0,t) $.

As mentioned briefly, $S$ is distributed lognormally with mean and variance as per the screenshot below.

In the article (see below) they start with the expected value under some measure $Q$. My understanding is that the general representation of expected values (using Lebesgue notation) is

$\begin{aligned} \mathop{{}\mathbb{E^Q}}[X] 
= \mathop{{}\int X \cdot dQ} \end{aligned}$

In the article however, they skip the $dQ$ step and start with $dF(S)$ with $F$ the cdf of $S$.

**Goal**: I would like to properly explain how $Q$ and $F$ are "interchangeable".

[image: Black-Scholes derivation through integration]

Comment: Might it be just a matter of notation where by $d \mathbb{Q}(S)$ they meant integration wrt the pushforward measure $S_* \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: This seems to be a notational issue. If you show the full set of equations from whence this "$dQ=dF$" came, we could clarify this. $d\Bbb Q(S)$ almost surely means integration against the pushforward and this is also what is typically meant by $dF(S)$ in the sense of Stieltjes integration

Comment: Pushforward measure is just another word for the *distribution* of a random variable. I'm sure you've heard of that! $F$ is a notation for the cumulative function associated to that very same distribution.

Comment: Fantastic, I think I should be able to formulate it more precisely in terms of this pushfoward terminology. Happy to accept it if it is worth posting as an answer.